# Events on function execution and completion in JS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, dom-events

I would like to know if there are any default events emitted when we invoke a function in nodejs and any events emitted when the callback/promise of the function is complete. If there are such events what are they called (i.e. By what name are they registered) and can we catch them using listener and do some manipulation?

Comment: No, there are no such events. You will want to manipulate the function itself instead.

Comment: @Bergi, so I can decorate all the functions following certain pattern and emit events on their invocation and completion, then I can listen to these events and do all manipulation that I need

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: On the other hand, depending on your use case, have a look at the debugger API of your engine, it does have profiling events and such stuff.

Comment: @TGW Could you get an answer for that during this while after you asked it here? I have the same issue and it rose with using the callbacks which are not invoked with an IO process and I wonder "so upon which event/caller this function is called?" I think that's likely a misunderstanding about JS environment internal flows, but I can not find the correct term or word to ask the proper question!

Comment: @BaN no I could not get an answer to it, I believe it is more like what Bergi said we will want to manipulate the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that are emitted by default.

You can easily implement callbacks within functions, like so:

```
function callbackFnOnCompletion(a, b, callbackFn) {
  // function body
   callbackFn();
}
```

Now, you can call it like so:

```
callbackFnOnCompletion(1, 2, () => console.log('Hi'));
```

For promises, `.then(fn)` and `.catch(fn)` are the best options.

```
Promise.resolve(1)
.then(() => console.log('Promise resolved'))
.catch(() => console.log('Promise rejected'))
```

Comment: sorry, the question was not elaborate enough but I understand how I can leverage callback itself but what I want is to have a way where no matter what function (created by developer) is invoked/executed I should be able to intercept this and do some of my stuff. For eg. AOP in Object Oriented Languages...

Comment: @TGW Fortunately JS is an OOP language and you can easily do AOP :-)